# Playing Connect 6?

Tags: probability, game-theory

Say I'm playing Connect 6, a variation of [Connect 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connect_Four), and I get to go first. For a $n \times n$ board, which position should I place my chip on to maximize my odds of winning?

Note than unlike Connect 4, Connect 6 requires 6 chips in a row. **Additionally, the chips are placed on a board, so you can place a chip on any unoccupied position, regardless of if theres a chip below it or not.**

Does it matter?

Comment: At least for $n\le 5$, it does not matter :)